# Geoposition takes a lot of time Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation

I have this following code where it works just fine on the Emulator. It gets a fake location i.e. Microsoft Location in Redmond but its quick. I deployed the same code on a Windows Phone 8.1 device and the Geopostion line literally takes like 5 minutes to get the latitude and longitude. Is there a way to get the latitude and longitude quicker just like here transit says getting your location but its quick. please help and let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
 Geolocator locator = new Geolocator();
                locator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                Geoposition position = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();

                latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude;
                longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this "too long to get current position", with this:

```
        geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
        geolocator.ReportInterval = 2000;
        geolocator.PositionChanged += geolocator_PositionChanged;


    private void geolocator_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (args.Position != null && args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate() != myPosition)
            {
                if(args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy <= 1500)
                {
                    myPosition = args.Position.Coordinate.ToGeoCoordinate();
                    UpDateMyPositionCircle(args.Position.Coordinate.Accuracy);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```